# Wordpress slider with filters & thumbnails outwith the slider

Tags: plugins, wordpress, slider

I am looking to create a slider within wordpress that is a little out of the norm and was wondering if anyone could give me advice on how to go about it.

I'd like a slider for a meet the team page on our website.

I am hoping the slider could work as normal but have filters on the left for departments and thumbnails below and outwith the slider with each employee on there.

I would like these thumbnails to be clickable and for the matching slide to appear when the thumbnail is clicked.

Can anyone suggest a plugin or a method to create this kind of thing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i think you are referring to isotope jquery plugin. It filters down items based on the selected tag. Its actually free but you will have to create modify it for your needs. If you are using bootstrap you can get the idea of implimentation from here. 
http://theme.stepofweb.com/Atropos/v1.5/HTML/page-team.html

Here is a paid wordpress plugin that can do that for you. 
http://codecanyon.net/item/meet-the-team-wordpress-plugin/full_screen_preview/4983412

Comment: Thank you very much Omer. I will look into that right now.

Comment: Omer - if I were to use the isotop jquery plugin within wordpress, would there be a way to have it link to slider with extended information above? p.s. thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Yes you can create your own html and use the classes to make it functional. A good place to start would be from copying all the code from this page and modifying it to your needs.http://www.designlunatic.com/demos/isotope/

Comment: Well reference website is not using isotope, they are just simple pages that are linked from a simple menu.

Comment: Interesting ... would you have a resource that would demonstrate how to create the one in the example so I can compare the two. I'm thinking maybe I can merge the two and have isotope at the bottom and the simple slider at the top? Thanks again Omer.

Comment: Ok now i get what you are talking about, actually you can use http://www.designlunatic.com/demos/isotope/ for the isotope impliemenation and then you can have different sliders for each category. Now when some one clicks on "permanent staff" all you have to do is hide rest of the sliders through jquery and just show the relavant one.

Comment: Exactly Omer .. I am just not sure how I would implement this idea using simple pages and a simple menu. If you have a resource I will research it and should be able to implement it once I have a step in the right direction. Your help has been excellent today, Thanks!

Comment: Well i have seen the code and it looks like they are using a custom slider. You can actually use a slider like flexslider or the one from bootstrap and modify it according to your needs. you already have a reference site so it would be preety simple to replicate it.

Comment: Thank you Omer ... You've been a great help.